# AngularJS doesn't detect value in input from address lookup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I have a web form using AngularJS form validation, however when I use the address lookup (using api/script from [loqate.com](https://www.loqate.com/)) the inputs are filled in from selecting an address but the AngularJS can't see the values. The form responds as if the inputs are empty.

The form validation all works fine, but when the inputs have values set via the address lookup the ng-model sees nothing, ng-change isn't triggered etc.

I've tried calling `$scope.$apply()` but whenever I do I get `$rootScope:inprog` console error.

The script the address lookup calls appears to be [this, but I can't make head nor tail of it](https://services.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/js/platformcaptureplus-2.33.min.js?key=JT75-DH51-EG46-XC17&BRAND=PostcodeAnywhere)

[Here is the form in action](https://npowerwhd-dev.azurewebsites.net). Address is on page 2, start entereing a postcode eg. 'PE' for address options.

Comment: What do you mean with "AngularJS can't see the values"? How do you set them after the address is selected from the dropdown? Could you post some HTML and AngularJS code?

Comment: @VirgilioGM the addresslookup is a service with a script provided by loqate, via their site I specify the name of the inputs to affect which I assume they use to create the script I linked. You start typing a postcode and a dropdown appears where you can click on an address, which them make the address lines appear in the specified inputs. I don't have to do anything to my site only call the script on load. I've linked the live form so you can see the form and addresslookup, the data appears in the inputs but the angularjs model doesn't change, it thinks they're empty.

Comment: And when were you trying to call `$scope.$apply()`?

Comment: I simply put a button on the page which would call it, which I'd try clicking after having selected an address. I tried calling Apply on the "next" button click as well but gave same inprog error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Loqate documentation you can use [event listeners](https://www.loqate.com/resources/support/setup-guides/advanced-setup-guide/#events_listeners) so you could update your model by adapting this code:

```
control.listen("populate", function(address, variations) {
    // I don't know what fields the received address variable has but
    // you just have to check it and apply the necessary changes.
    $scope.Contact.address1_postalcode = address.PostalCode;
    $scope.Contact.address1_line1 = address.Street;
    $scope.Contact.address1_city = address.City;
    $scope.Contact.address1_country = address.Country;
});
```